# Eigenvalues of "$A^{1/2}B^{-1}A^{1/2}$" equal to 1

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, positive-definite

I found the following statement in a book:

For matrices $A$ and $B$ both symmetric and positive definite, if the eigenvalues of:
$$A^{1/2}B^{-1}A^{1/2},$$
are all equal to 1, than $A$ is identical to  $B$.

How can I prove such statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the matrix $A^{1/2}B^{-1}A^{1/2}$ is symmetric for obvious reasons. All its eigenvalues are equal to $1$, and the only symmetric matrix with such a property is the identity matrix, hence
$$A^{1/2}B^{-1}A^{1/2}=I.$$
After that multiply this identity by $A^{-1/2}$ from the left and from  the right, which leads to $$B^{-1}=A^{-1}$$ and $$B=A.$$